# X2Go Public Key Authentication not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, 22.04, authentication, aws, x2go

```
Software Versions:
X2Go Client 4.1.1.1
Ubuntu 22.04
```

I've been using X2Go on AWS for a couple years. X2Go client is installed on my workspace, and I run the server on EC2 instances to allow graphics. If I don't need to run graphics I just ssh into the EC2 instance from an xterm since public key authentication is setup.

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 on my EC2 instances. The public key authentication in X2Go doesn't work in 22.04. I went back and verified that it works fine in 20.04. I had always used the "Use RSA/DSA key for ssh connection:" box with nothing below it checked. I have tried just that box, that box plus "Try auto login (via SSH agent or default SSH key)" checked, and just "Try auto login (via SSH agent or default SSH key)" checked with nothing in the "Use RSA/DSA key for ssh connection:" box. When I try and login it always pops up a box asking for my password.
[Session Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeqwc.png)

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a work around?

Thanks,

Gene

Comment: What does /var/log/auth.log tell you about the problem?

Comment: Thanks Robert. It logged "userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms". So I looked up PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms and saw in the sshd_config 5 man page that PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms is used to set the key type in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. So I went into that file and uncommented the "PubkeyAuthentication yes" line, and added a "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa" line. I then rebooted the instance. It no longer asks for a password.

Comment: But now I get a "Connection failed. bash: line 1: x2golistsessions: command not found" LoL. I haven't started debugging that yet. Any hints welcome. I'll list what I find. Best, Gene

Comment: try sudo apt-get install x2goclient

Answer (score 1):

The "Connection failed" error was because I was using  an ancient install script that did not work correctly. Yes, a reinstall fixed that issue. Then I got a strange “Authentication is required to create color managed device” popup message. I implemented a fix I found online creating a file named /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/ containing

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
 if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile") &&
 subject.isInGroup("{users}")) {
 return polkit.Result.YES;
 }
 });
```

X2Go works correctly now, but it seems to be running a bit slow. Anyway, the fix to the original authentication issue is in the comments above. Uncommented the "PubkeyAuthentication yes" line, and added a "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa" line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Thanks Robert